# How we can change administrator path in joomla?

Tags: joomla

I want to change administrator path of mysite in joomla. ex. currently i have admin path `http://myserver/mysite/administrator` but now i want to change it

```
http://myserver/mysite/admin .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the constants in `/includes/defines.php and /administrator/includes/defines.php`

Comment: i have change that but nothing works... I think some more modification is require for this

Comment: @Pramod you also have to rename the folder `administrator` to `admin` under `mysite`

Comment: @ppeterka by changing the folder name will it work properly ?

Comment: @Pramod I didn't try it. What I'm sure is that without changing it, it is sure that it won't work... Please read what Watch Insiders wrote, I can not confirm that, but it seems possible that you are up to a frustrating challenge by attempting this...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Joomla doesn't have a clean way of changing this without changing core files and even then this will cause problems while applying update patches in the future.

What you should consider is installing jSecure, an an extension which will prevent people from hitting mysite.com/administrator page directly. You can access your admin panel by going to mysite.com/administrator?MySecretKey (set your own secret key) but people who try to access it directly will be redirected to the front page.

I hope this helps.